# Converting C++ code to Mips

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, pcspim

I am converting a C++ project in Mips assembly language. In c++ you can initialize an array like

```
int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

How can I initialize an array of characters in MIPS assembly language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MIPS assembly you would instruct the assembler to statically allocate enough memory for the array, and its initial value using the directives `.data` and `.word`.
E.g:

```
.data
arrayOfInts:
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
arrayOfChars
.word 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

This works for compile-time defined variables. If your intent is to dynamically allocate the array you'd have to do it yourself.

Comment: Does this work with .space cuz I am getting error with .space

Comment: @UmerFarooq: With `.space` you have to tell the assembler how many bytes to reserve, but not the actual values. e.g. `.space 32` to reserve 32 bytes

Comment: I have used .byte but I get "Memory out of bound error" in QTSPIM

Comment: The directive is a compile-time mechanism. If you are getting this error at runtime then i guess its not related to this directive. If you are getting that error at compile-time maybe you need to put first a `.data` directive (e.g. `.data 0x2000`) to tell the compiler where is your data segment.